# What does uninitialized constant mean?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, uninitialized-constant

I'm getting the error `uninitialized constant SessionsController` I've searched, and can only find explanations of this error in reference to a `NameError` Does anyone know what the error means?

Comment: It means exactly what it says, that the variable by that name is uninitialized. It's referring to it as a constant because it's capitalized.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit? SessionsController is supposed to be capitalized.

Comment: Right. But it hasn't been defined yet. This is a standard error message for any attempt to access a capitalized variable that is undefined.

Comment: If you thought it _should_ have been defined, you'll have to share some code and assert why you believe that to be the case.

Comment: That's fine, I have another questions that is specifically about solving the error. I just wanted to know what the error message specifically meant so I could better understand what was going on. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19057217/uninitialized-constant-sessionscontroller-in-api/19058081#19058081

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is one of two "subtypes of" `Name Error` dealing with uninitialized variables. The language of "uninitialized constant" is due to the fact that `SessionsController` is capitalized. Both types are illustrated below:

```
new-host-3:bot palfvin$ irb
2.0.0p247 :001 > foobar
NameError: undefined local variable or method `foobar' for main:Object
    from (irb):1
    from /Users/palfvin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'
2.0.0p247 :002 > Foobar
NameError: uninitialized constant Foobar
    from (irb):2
    from /Users/palfvin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'
2.0.0p247 :003 >
```

Answer (score 3):

It means that you're trying to use a Class or a Module that wasn't defined yet. Probably because you forgot to require them.

Make sure that this class `SessionsController` has been declared in your `sessions_controller.rb`.

Read more: http://ruby.about.com/od/faqs/qt/Nameerror-Uninitialized-Constant-Object-Something.htm